replacing product incorrect account number
I am having issues trying to correct a single string into a correctly formatted account name.
Dim aaa As String = "FLACCT1717300000009"
aaa = aaa.Replace("FL", "FL-")
aaa = aaa.Replace("ACCT", "ACCT-")
aaa = aaa.ToString.Replace("00000", "-")
Debug.Print(aaa)

I am looking for account = FL-ACCT-171730-09
but its producing incorrectly = FL-ACCT-17173-009

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-8.0

Regex.Replace() -> pattern: (.{2})(.{4})(.{6})(.{5})(..), replacement: $1-$2-$3-$5

@Jimi, That's a high level answer, I'd if you post a full answer with that to let us all get the knowledge, and OP can go with my basic answer or the highest one

The following may be of interest: Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference.

@MustafaMutasim: Regarding @Jimi's comment for regular expressions. If you  click on the URL in my previous comment. For the meaning of () look under the heading Grouping Constructs (see ( subexpression ).  For the meaning of ., look under the heading Character Classes.  For {2}, look under the heading Quantifiers (see { n }).

@user246821, Thank you for taking the time to consider my request, you make it easy to understand, I know that Regular Expression is very important topic, however, I did not give it the required time to learn it

You are replacing five zeros instead of six. Change the line to aaa = aaa.ToString.Replace("000000", "-")

@HardCode, OP looking for more, see his reply on the answer

Dim aaa As String = "FLACCT1717300000009"

Dim part_1 As String = aaa.Substring(0, 2)
Dim part_2 As String = aaa.Substring(2, 4)
Dim part_3 As String = aaa.Substring(6, 6)
Dim part_4 As String = aaa.Substring(12, 5)
Dim part_5 As String = aaa.Substring(17, 2)

Dim account As String = String.Concat(part_1, "-", part_2, "-", part_3, "-", part_5)

Debug.Print(account)


your method is nice but accs like this  "FLACCT123400000111" wouldn't work, the output would need to be "FL-ACCT-1234-111"

You have to give a sample of all account types to get a full answer that fits all

@swissrockie - The string "FLACCT123400000111" is a different length than "FLACCT1717300000009". You need to be specific, in your question, as to what the inputs can be.

@swissrockie, your question specifically states one and only one input value and this answer addresses that value, so it answers the question you actually asked. If you want an answer to a different question then you should have asked that question. Don't expect us to read your mind.
